# How to write apex batch class to avoid too many email invocation send email

Tags: apex-email-service

I have a code in which is basically used to send email about appointments But when I try to send for a bunch of people for a date interval. The number of email to be sent is increased and as a result the Messaging.sendEmail() is invoked more than ten times. Previously I used List mails = new List and added all the mails into this list
as mails.add(mail) inside the for loop and sended as Messaging.SendEmail(mails). This was working some extent in Sandbox for a greater date range. But then when I deployed the code to production, error came as No_Mass_Mail_Permission Single email is not enabled for your organization. [image]

```
public void mailblock(string email,string repid,string CCEmail,string alterEmails,string GroupMail,string Choice,string RepName){
   // sendDocAttach(email,CCEmail);
    system.debug('email: '+email);
    system.debug('repid: '+repid);
    system.debug('CCEmail: '+CCEmail);
    system.debug('alterEmails: '+alterEmails);
    system.debug('GroupMail: '+GroupMail);
    system.debug('Choice: '+Choice);
    system.debug('RepName: '+RepName);



    System.debug('Mailblock function Entry:::::');
    lstEvent=[Select Description,id,StartDateTime,LeadID__c,ActivityDate , EndDateTime,SalesrepID__c,Assigned_Sales_rep__c  From Event where SalesrepID__c=:RepId and ActivityDate>=:Date.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fDate'))and ActivityDate<=:Date.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('TDate')) ];
    List<Date> seDate = new List<Date>();
    DateTime FDate=DateTime.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fDate')+' 00:00:00');
    DateTime TDate=DateTime.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('tDate')+' 00:00:00');
   if(FDate!=null && TDate!=null){
        seDate = gensedate(FDate,TDate);
   }
    System.Debug('MyDate'+seDate);
    Datetime myDT = Datetime.now();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    if(seDate.size()>0){
        for(Date d:seDate){
            string sending='0';
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { email });
            mail.setCCAddresses(new String[] { CCEmail });
            String[] BCCAddressList = new String[]{};
            string emails='';
            String[] BCCAddresses = new String[]{};
            if(alterEmails!='' && alterEmails!=null){
                BCCAddresses.add(alterEmails);
            }
            if(GroupMail!='' && GroupMail!=null){
                BCCAddresses.add(GroupMail);
            }
            if(BCCAddresses.size()>0){
                mail.setBCCAddresses( BCCAddresses );
            }
           // mail.setHtmlBody('http://premiercare.force.com/AppSheet?id='+RepId+'&fdate='+String.ValueOf(d).replace(' 00:00:00',''));
            // Send the email

            if(lstEvent.size()>0){
                system.debug('lstEvent values:::::::');



            for(Event E:lstEvent){
                if(E.SalesrepID__c==RepId && E.ActivityDate==Date.valueOf(d)){
                    System.Debug('RepName++'+RepName);
                    string CS=string.ValueOf(d)+' 00:00:00';

                    AppEmailMap__c objAppEmail= new AppEmailMap__c();
                    objAppEmail.SalesRepId__c=RepId;
                    objAppEmail.SalesRep__c=RepId;
                    objAppEmail.AppDate__c=Date.valueOf(d);
                    insert objAppEmail;
                    objAppEmail.Appt_Sheet_Link__c=URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/apex/VFAppoinment?id='+RepId+'&fdate=' +String.ValueOf(d).replace(' 00:00:00','')+'&EId='+string.valueof(objAppEmail.Id);
                    update objAppEmail;

                    mail.setSubject(RepName+' check your Appoinment(s) on ' +  String.ValueOf(DateTime.ValueOf(CS).format('MM-dd-yyyy')).replace(' 00:00:00',''));
                    if(checkboxValue=='false')
                    {
                    Document doc = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Document WHERE Name = 'Required Finance Documents Form'];
                    mail.setDocumentAttachments(new ID[]{doc.id});
                    }
                    mail.setHtmlBody('Your AppointmentSheet:'+'To View Appointments <a href=http://premiercare.force.com/AppSheet?id='+RepId+'&fdate=' +String.ValueOf(d).replace(' 00:00:00','')+'&EId='+string.valueof(objAppEmail.Id)+'>click here</a><br/><br/><b><i><font size="2">Please keep in mind that appointment timesheet links are only accessible within 24 hours of the appointment date. Please check back if necessary (i.e. Holidays, etc.) as it is your responsibility to attend appointments on time regardless of when your timesheets are received.</font></i></b>');
                    //mails.add(mail);
                    system.debug('mails: '+mails);
                    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail }); 

                    sending='1';
                    break;
                }
            }
            //Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
            system.debug('executed');

          }

          if(Choice=='1'){
               if(sending=='0'){
                   System.Debug('RepName++&'+RepName);
                   string CS=string.ValueOf(d)+' 00:00:00';
                   if(checkboxvalue=='false')
                    {
                    Document doc = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Document WHERE Name = 'Required Finance Documents Form'];
                    mail.setDocumentAttachments(new ID[]{doc.id});
                    }
                    mail.setSubject(RepName+' Appoinment not Scheduled on ' +  String.ValueOf(DateTime.ValueOf(CS).format('MM-dd-yyyy')).replace(' 00:00:00',''));
                    mail.setHtmlBody('Appointment not available on'+ String.ValueOf(DateTime.ValueOf(CS).format('MM-dd-yyyy')).replace(' 00:00:00','') );
                   // Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                   mails.add(mail);

               }
           }else{
               sending='1';
           }
          }
           Messaging.sendEmail(mails); 
    }else{
        system.debug('Else part Entry');
       send(email,repid,CCEmail,alterEmails);

    }
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Email with PDF sent to '+email + ' and '+ CCEmail ));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting that error is because under your production profile you don't have the MASS Email and/or Send Email permission. If you are an administrator go on your profile and enable those.

Note: The Mass Email functionality is available only in the Professional, Enterprise or Unlimited Edition

Answer (score 0):

I checked in profile the send email permission was enabled and also in deliver-ability the access was given to all emails.

The issue is because of the way the Document is attached to the mail.

Now I have used EmailFileAttachment for attaching the document.

here is the code:

```
Document doc = [select id, name, body, contenttype, developername, type from Document WHERE Name = 'Required Finance Documents Form'];
                    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                    attach.setContentType(doc.contentType);
                    attach.setFileName(doc.developerName+'.'+doc.type);
                    attach.setInline(false);
                    attach.Body = doc.Body;
                    mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach });
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced one of the similar issues but the error message said "NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION, Single email is not enabled for your organization or profile."

I fixed the issue with a change in settings.

Check you Deliverabililty settings under Setup > Email Administration > Deliverability.  My issue was that we had the setting set to No Access.  It must be set to All Email.